# undefined reference errors while compiling a QT program

Tags: qt

I just installed QtSDK 1.2 on my redhat enterprise linux 5.6. While compiling a QT program, I got the following errors:

```
[root@stack example1]# make
g++ -m64 -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath,/opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/gcc/lib -o example1 fac1.o    -L/opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/gcc/lib -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread 
/opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/gcc/lib/libQtCore.so: undefined reference to `g_main_context_push_thread_default'
/opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/gcc/lib/libQtCore.so: undefined reference to `inotify_init1@GLIBC_2.9'
/opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/gcc/lib/libQtGui.so: undefined reference to `pipe2@GLIBC_2.9'
/opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/gcc/lib/libQtCore.so: undefined reference to `g_main_context_pop_thread_default'
/opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/gcc/lib/libQtGui.so: undefined reference to `FcFreeTypeQueryFace'
/opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/gcc/lib/libQtGui.so: undefined reference to `FT_Library_SetLcdFilter'
/opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/gcc/lib/libQtGui.so: undefined reference to `__longjmp_chk@GLIBC_2.11'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [example1] Error 1
[root@stack example1]#
```

It seems g++ compiler uses all correct options. Befor I installed QtSDK 1.2 on rhel 5.6, I had copied libstdc++.so.6.0.10 to /usr/lib64 and relinked libstdc++.so.6 to libstdc++.so.6.0.10, since QtSDK requires GLIBCXX_3.4.9 symbols in the libstdc++ library. I think this may be the source of the problem. But I'm not sure about that. So any advice? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is multiple questions:

- Are you in a 64 architecture? If not why using 64 libraries?
- Did the libraries copied are 64 versions ?

  - If it is the case, why do you need to copy them, there should already be standard libraries in `/usr/lib64`
  - If it is not the case the errors are legit.
- How did you compiled Qt in the first place? if your Qt libraries are really 64 bits, then it means the environment setup was already correct.

Comment: Yes, it's on a 64 architecture. Originally, rhel 5.6 uses libstdc++-4.1.2-50.el5, but QtSDK requires GLIBCXX_3.4.8 which is not included in libstdc++-4.1.2, so I downloaded libstdc++-4.3.2-7.x86_64.rpm from rpm.pbone.net and extracted libstdc++.so.6.0.10 to /usr/libc64. I didn't compile Qt from source. Should I do so?

Comment: Did you changed the libraries before installing Qt?

Comment: Yes. Unless I relink /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 to the newly copied libstdc++.so.6.0.10, QtSDK installation would not proceed.

Comment: Well, it's so wierd, my .pro file doesn't contain requird header files. I've included all the header files included in QtGui. Now, make produces new error messages:         moc_qactiongroup.cpp:78: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct QActionGroupPrivate’
/opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/gcc/include/QtGui/qactiongroup.h:55: error: forward declaration of ‘struct QActionGroupPrivate

Comment: You have an issue with your library path in general. And there might be Qt libs inside /usr/lib or somewhere else.

Comment: rhel 5.6 has qt-3.3 installed by default. Should I replace all library files in /usr/lib to libraries of Qt 4.8.0?

Comment: I have compiled qt libraries from source and now it works now. Thanks UmNyobe.